# unable to get email address, location, values using oauth.io

Tags: javascript, oauth.io

I am integrating facebook, twitter, github, linkedin using https://oauth.io/signin third party site.
I integrated facebook and was able to successfully get id, name, gender properties directly but am seeing difficulty in getting email address, location values.

[image]

In oauth.io site, I even added scope permissions for facebook

[image]

I am using the below code to get info of the logged in user.

```
OAuth.popup('facebook')
            .done(function (result) {
                res = result;
                result.me().done(function (response) {
                    debugger;
                    console.log('me ' + response.name);
                    console.log('me ' + response.email);

                });
            })
            .fail(function (error) {
                alert('fail');
            });
```

I even tried filtering the results only to give email, birthdate values using

```
OAuth.popup('facebook')
            .done(function (result) {
                res = result;
                result.me(['email', 'birthdate', 'location']).done(function (response) {
                    debugger;
                    console.log('me ' + response.name);
                    console.log('me ' + response.email);

                });
            })
            .fail(function (error) {
                alert('fail');
            });
```

But it just returned empty object.
Can some one let me know if I am missing something?

Comment: did you fix it? I am facing the same issue. facebook is working fine but not able to configure linkedin n google. on oauth.io it is working fine. Not able to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get the required fields for facebook using

```
 result.get('/me?fields=name,email,gender,birthday').done(function (response) {
                    console.log('me ' + response.name); 
  });
```

But the same code is not working for twitter.
Still looking for an answer which works in a generic way for most of the apis

Comment: Hi - did you find an answer to the problem?

Comment: Thanks! this is strange - for us it works with twitter & google+; we only have the problem with Facebook. Btw, are you still using oauth.io, or did you find an alternative?

Comment: am still with oauth.io

Comment: fyi: the issue has been fixed: https://github.com/oauth-io/oauthd/commit/7beec64ab39955c3afd2eb28ecf7288c74ccdc96